# How to turn off xwindow screen saver?

Tags: desktop, screensaver, xset

I'm using xfce-desktop environment.I want to turn off the screen saver. What I have tried:

1. `xset s 0 0`
2. `xset s off`
3. 

```
sleep 1; xset s off
sleep 1; xset s noblank
```

The `xset q` command result:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Not working. My screen will still turn to sleep mode. Could anyone give me some advice please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xset -dpms` should do it.

If you look, its standby, suspend and off are all set to 600 seconds, 10 minutes.

I've no experience with xfce, but the link [xfce disable dpms](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932931/how-do-i-disable-xfce-display-power-management-in-xubuntu-16-04-at-the-command-l) should also work.

Comment: It Works! A huge Thank to you! You save my day~